# unable to install BIRT in eclipse helios

Tags: java, birt

I am unale to install BIRT on eclipse

I am downloading from
http://download.eclipse.org/birt/update-site/4.2

getting error

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found. 
>     Software being installed: Eclipse BIRT Example
>   4.2.2.v201210101433-7T7D7DDZRDKRKELIKjed (org.eclipse.birt.example.feature.group
>   4.2.2.v201210101433-7T7D7DDZRDKRKELIKjed)   Missing requirement: BIRT Data Engine 4.2.0.v20120612 (org.eclipse.birt.data 4.2.0.v20120612)
>   requires 'bundle org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer
>   [3.2.5,4.0.0)' but it could not be found   Missing requirement: BIRT
>   Data Engine 4.2.1.v201209121213 (org.eclipse.birt.data
>   4.2.1.v201209121213) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer [3.2.5,4.0.0)' but it
>   could not be found   Missing requirement: BIRT Data Engine
>   4.2.2.v201302011519 (org.eclipse.birt.data 4.2.2.v201302011519) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer
>   [3.2.5,4.0.0)' but it could not be found   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: BIRT Chart-Report Integration 4.2.0.v20120611 (org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem 4.2.0.v20120611)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.birt.data [2.1.0,5.0.0)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: BIRT Chart-Report Integration 4.2.1.v20120820 (org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem 4.2.1.v20120820)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.birt.data [2.1.0,5.0.0)   Cannot satisfy dependency:

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are installing BIRT 4.2.2 on top of Eclipse Helios (3.6.2). Birt version must be compatible with Eclipse version. If you want to use BIRT with Eclipse Helios, you must download BIRT 2.6.2. You can find it on http://archive.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/build.php?build=R-R1-2_6_2-201102191842.